# How to add a frame in a ggplot under cowplot library?

Tags: r, ggplot2, border, cowplot

recently I started to use `cowplot` library. I'm a huge fan of the plot frames, however it seems that `cowplot` doesn't allow it. Anyone knows a trick to create a frame in plots with `cowplot`?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

A <- c(rep(1, times = 3), rep(2, times = 3))
B0 <- c(rep("Text1", times = 3), rep("Text2", times = 3))
B <- factor(B0)
C <- c(0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 8.40, 9.00, 9.60)
D <- c(-7.3, -2.17, 1.05, -3.69, -5.04, -0.746)
DF <- data.frame(A, B, C, D)

ggplot(DF, aes(x = C, y = D , colour = B)) +
  geom_point() + geom_line() + facet_grid(~ B, scales = "free") +
  labs(x = "Axis X", y = "Axis Y") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(expression("R"[0]))) +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(size = 0.35)) #<- no frame
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you loading cowplot? Try `theme_light()`, with/without loading cowplot.

Comment: @zx8754 I use `cowplot` for arrangements like this https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/plot_grid.html

Comment: Then maybe expand your example to include cowplot involvement?